# Homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

1. For which odd values of $p$ can we find a non-trivial homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ ?
2. Is there any method to find those homeomorphisms explicitly?

I have no any idea to handle this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Homomorphisms are defined by their value on generators.

Comment: If you want homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z_p$ to $\Bbb Z_3$, then $\varphi(1_3)$ makes no sense ($1_3$ is an element of $\Bbb Z_3$, but $\varphi$ takes elements from $\Bbb Z_p$). $\varphi(1_p)$, on the other hand...

Comment: Thank you. I feel, now I can do something :). Also, can we find the number of such homomorphisms without find them explicitly.

Comment: @Nilan note you're talking about *homomorphisms* not homeomorphisms - those are something else.

Comment: The number of homomorphisms is given as follows: There are only three possible functions that _can_ be homomorphisms, namely the ones given by sending $1_p$ to $0_3$, $1_3$ or to $2_3$ (and extending by linearity). One of those is the trivial one, and it is always a homomorphism. As for the other two, if one of them is a homomorphism, then the other one is as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:\ \Bbb{Z}_p\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}_3$ is a homomorphism, then for every $k\in\Bbb{Z}_p$ we have
$$f(k)=f(1+1+\ldots+1)=f(1)+f(1)+\ldots+f(1)=k\cdot f(1),$$
which shows that $f$ is entirely determined by the value of $f(1)$. Now in $\Bbb{Z}_3$ we have $3=0$, so
$$f(3)=3\cdot f(1)=0\cdot f(1)=0,$$
which shows that $3\in\ker(f)$. If $f$ is nontrivial then $\ker(f)\neq\Bbb{Z}_p$, so $3$ must not generate all of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. If $p$ is prime, this is only the case if $p=3$. In this case there are precisely two nontrivial homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

For a group homomorphism $\phi$ which maps into $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ to be non trivial it must be surjective. This means something in the image of $\phi$ must have order $3$.

Since the order of $\phi(x)$ divides the order of $x$ for any homomorphism $\phi$ and element $x$, the order of $x$ must be a multiple of $3$. By Lagranges theorem, $|\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}|$ must be divisible by $3$, hence $3|p$ is a necessary condition.

This is also a sufficient condition though as you can then construct a nontrivial surjective homomorphism, which I will leave to you to do.